# Kinesis Video stream async get frames

Tags: python, python-asyncio, video-processing, amazon-kinesis

I would like to capture a video stream from AWS Kinesis and use `asyncio`. My goal is to extract frames from the stream and pass them to processing queue.

Below is the working example of what I have so far. It receives chunks of data of various length (may be in range of, say, 76 bytes up to 8192) which do not seem to be a complete frame.

Is there a cheap way to split the stream to chunks with support of asyncio and preferrably without threads?

I want one application to handle at least 10-20 streams and to have one application per CPU running on server.

I was thinking about `ffmpeg` and `opencv`, but they seem too heavyweight and do not seem to be good compatible with `asyncio`.

```
import asyncio

import aiobotocore

VIDEO_STREAM_NAME = 'bc-test1'


async def get_data2(loop):
    chunk_size = 1024 * 1024 * 500
    session = aiobotocore.get_session(loop=loop)
    async with session.create_client('kinesisvideo', region_name='us-west-2', ) as client:
        resp = await client.get_data_endpoint(
            StreamName=VIDEO_STREAM_NAME,
            APIName='GET_MEDIA',
        )
        data_url = resp['DataEndpoint']

    async with session.create_client('kinesis-video-media', endpoint_url=data_url) as client:
        resp = await client.get_media(
            StreamName=VIDEO_STREAM_NAME,
            StartSelector={"StartSelectorType": "NOW", },
        )
        print(resp)
        while True:
            data = await resp['Payload'].read(1024 * 8)
            if data:
                print("frame len: %s" % len(frame))
            else:
                print("No data")
                break


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_data2(loop))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would consider advices to do not use `asyncio` with another solution to satisfy the requirements above.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: Nope. I gave up and it yet was not implemented. I'd still love to find the good answer.

Comment: So, i was looking for the same thing. I ended up extracting each chunk from from stream, converting chunks into mkv, extracting frames, and doing down stream processes. This all is in ecs image. Each stream extraction is well managed and can be scaled when we add more streams and do heavy processing.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be python?

KinesisVideoStream has examples in Java to consume the stream, parse the data and decode the video: https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library

KinesisVideoStream also has KIT: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/analyze-live-video-at-scale-in-real-time-using-amazon-kinesis-video-streams-and-amazon-sagemaker/
It can be used to process video streams in scale.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I am a Python programmer and another part of the project is on Python too. I know how to make it working with synchronous frameworks, but the approach was to use `asyncio`.